Where are DataTable and DataColumn in WinUI 3?
I want to use DataGrid in WinUI 3, and I noticed that the WinUI3 gallery and the Windows Community Toolkit gallery have different DataGrid table controls.
I can’t find where the DataTable is located.
I found the DataGrid on NuGet, but I also saw "DataTable" mentioned in the Windows Community Toolkit Gallery under Controls > Layout > DataTable. To use controls:DataColumn, as shown in the Windows Community Toolkit Gallery samples, which NuGet package should I install?
This is part of the sample I found in the gallery.
<Page x:Class="DataTableExperiment.Samples.DataTableSample"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:controls="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls"
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
      xmlns:local="using:DataTableExperiment.Samples"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
      mc:Ignorable="d">

    <ListView ItemsSource="{x:Bind InventoryItems}">
        <ListView.Header>
            <controls:DataTable Margin="12,0,0,0">
                <controls:DataColumn Content="Id"
                                     DesiredWidth="80" />
                <controls:DataColumn MinWidth="120"
                                     CanResize="True"
                                     Content="Name" />



To use the DataTable control from CommunityToolkit-Labs:

On the NuGet Package Manager, go to Settings (gear icon) and add the Lab's NuGet package source from Settings.
https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dotnet/CommunityToolkit/_packaging/CommunityToolkit-Labs/nuget/v3/index.json

Enable only the Lab's NuGet package source.

Enable Initial prerelease.

Search for CommunityToolkit.Labs.WinUI.Controls.DataTable and install it.

Add the corresponding namespace.
xmlns:labs="using:CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Controls"


Use the control:
<labs:DataTable />




Thank you very much! I was able to find it.
This was my first time adding a prerelease version, so it was a great learning experience.

It seems that CommunityToolkit.DataTable control is not public, the link is invalid.
https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Windows/tree/main/components/DataTable
It is recommended that you use DataGrid. However, you can find the Labs-components here https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Labs-Windows/tree/main/components/DataTable

Thank you for letting me know.I was able to find it from the prerelease version.
However, I wonder why it's unlinked from the gallery app.
I’m unsure whether it’s the right choice to add it to the app while it’s still in a prerelease state.
I really hope a great DataTable feature comes to WinUI 3 soon!
